# Deleting from arraylist and exporting back to .buab file(Java)

Tags: java

Ive made an address book.  I can currently write to the arraylist and save it back to the .buab file, but I cant delete from the arraylist and export it back to the .buab file?

Im pretty much stuck on this. Im able to retrive contacts from the .buab and scroll through them using the JTextFields and buttons ive created.
Any help will be dearly appreciated.

Ive set up seprate classes for all operations (newcontacts, nextcontact etc).

If you need the code posted let me know..
Cheers

Dave

Comment: retagged as homework since it's a assignement

Comment: It would be nice if these guys would talk to the prof or tutor or other people in the class about the assignment. Or at least they could learn to search the forums. I've lost track of the number of questions related to this assignment that have been posted in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting stuff from a list is as easy as adding:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
myListOfContacts.add(contact);    // adds a contact
myListOfContacts.remove(contact); // removes the contact
```

No more magic needed.

**Edit**

Please, and this is not Java, strictly separate three things, and your life will become much, much easier:

1. The model - your contacts stored in your arraylist(s)
2. The view - Your JFrame, showing the data from the model (the list(s))
3. The Controller - The code behind your buttons that does something with the model (adding, removing, changing data on the array list)

Maybe you've heard of the MVC pattern (model-view-controller).

So you don't 'export your' JList: on your View (the JFrame), you press a button and some code from your Controller (actually what you might have in your buttons action listener) is executed to write the model (your arraylist(s)) to the file.

Same goes for deleting, adding, importing. You 'do' something on the view (the GUI) to affect changes to the model (the list(s)).

As I said, this is not Java, this is a very, very common pattern for object oriented languages. Look at your code, try to find the model, the view, the controller and try to separate the code. Promise, once you've done it, the next assignements will be a joke.

Comment: and before closing the application don't forget the save ArrayLists in file

Comment: the contact information will be shown through the JTextFields, so the current contact information in the index will need to be deleted.
Sorry im as thick as they come with java

Comment: @Dave, you can delete from a ArrayList using the index, like txtNum.remove(index);

Answer (score 0):

public void export(){
        try {
            BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    "contacts.buab", true));
            fileOut.write(temp);

```
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.getMessage());
    }
    txtName.setText("");
    txtHomeNum.setText("");
    txtMobNum.setText("");
    txtHomeAdd.setText("");


}
```

Comment: instead fileOut.wirte(temp)  do a loop to write your arraylists data.